# MadExcept can no longer mail our bugs after changing from MAPI to OAUTH on MS recommendations

Tags: email, delphi, office365, madexcept

Is it possible to have MadExcept to send mail using the new MS Office365 mailservers? MAPI is no longer an option.

Comment: Ask at madshi's forum

Comment: [He's answering every topic that can be answered](http://forum.madshi.net/viewforum.php?f=4) - an exceptional service and worth registering a board account for free.